# ggplot: no color in plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to add color to my ggplot but I cannot seem to get it to work. I have a function PlotAllLayers that automatically adds everything from my data.frame into the plot. Now I want to add the 'Dark2' palette but it does not seem to work.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(0:100)
df <- sapply(seq(5,100,by=10), function(n) dbinom(x,n,.6))
df <- data.frame(x,df)

plotAllLayers<-function(df){
  p<-ggplot(data=df,aes(df[,1]))
  for(i in names(df)[-1]){ 
    p<-p+geom_line(aes_string(y=i))
  }
  return(p)
}

testplot <- plotAllLayers(df)
testplot <- testplot + scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
print(testplot)
```

Comment: Please never include `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))` at the top of your script. Sometimes, we have important data loaded into our sessions, and it is easy to mindlessly copy in your script and wipe out all our data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your technique of iteratively adding layers in a function forces you to iteratively assign colour names. This is not the canonical way to use `ggplot`. Instead, `melt` your data first, and everything becomes easy:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
# Melt your data:
melted.df<-melt(df,id.vars='x')
#   x variable   value
# 1 0       X1 0.01024
# 2 1       X1 0.07680
# 3 2       X1 0.23040

# Plot.
ggplot(melted.df,aes(x=x,y=value,colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
# Warning that this palette doesn't support 10 colours.
```

Comment: Please add back the data into your question! I just meant to remove that first line. Also, if you like the answer, click the checkmark to the left of the answer.